# Angular Não consigo criar um componente com o ng g c

Tags: angular

Ola estou tentando usar o comando para criar componente chamado sidebar no angular o ng g c sidebar
porem quando aperto enter o terminal fica como na foto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está no diretório certo?

Comment: estava sim, não sei era algum bug formatei a maquina voltou ao normal, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de tudo certifique se o diretório está correto.

1 - Utilizar o terminal cmd com atalho (ctrl + shift + c), ai tu digita esse comando.
2 - atualizando o angular-cli: ng update
Caso continue, crie um projeto novo para desencargo.

Abs.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-ask).